# ASP.Net Web Service: Redirecting from a WebMethod to another Webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have written the following WebService in Demo.asmx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyAccount
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Demo
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Demo : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(int hw)
        {
            Server.TransferRequest("Demo.asmx?op=HelloWorld2");
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld2(int hw)
        {
            return "Hello World2";
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am expecting is that from WebMethod HelloWorld, on click of invoke, the request to be transferred to HelloWorld2 WebMethod. The following is the actual output:

1. Browse the Demo.asmx in Chrome
   [Browse the Demo.asmx in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5QJN.png)
2. Click the HelloWorld WebMethod
   [Click the HelloWorld WebMethod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYQm8.png)
3. Enter the value 2 and click on Invoke
   [Showing ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y2EM.png)

What was expected: On click of invoke, the server should transfer the request to HelloWorld2 WebMethod and then load the WebMethod of HelloWorld2 like:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VEHL.png)

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why transfer the request? Can't you just call and return result of `HelloWorld2` from `HelloWorld`?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to transfer the request in case of some dependent events. For example, if the value of the variable 'hw' in HelloWorld WebMethod is 1, then i have to show the HelloWorld1 WebMethod to the user. If it is 2, then show the HelloWorld2 WebMethod to the user. And so on.

Comment: You don't have to transfer the request for doing this? e.g.  in `HelloWorld`


`if (hw==1)
  {    return "value from HelloWorld1"; }
else if (hw==2)
   {   return HelloWorld2(hw); }
`

Comment: But how to show the HelloWorld2 WebMethod UI in that case? I have to show the UI so that the user can enter some value to the HelloWorld2 WebMethod

Comment: Is this something recently developed? asmx is very old technology now.

Comment: Asmx technology is very old. But at my workplace, they are using it.

Comment: Please see that the parameter to the WebMethod HelloWorld2 is passed by the user (via the WebMethod UI) and not from the previous WebMethod (HelloWorld)